# How to compare the number of clusters for large data sets?

Tags: python, r, bigdata, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am trying to cluster a data set with about 1,100,000 observations, each with three values. As I do not know the right number of clusters, I tried hierarchical clustering, but it requires 4095 GB memory to solve the problem. as an alternative, I used K-means and solved the problem for k=2 to 10. The problem now is I cannot find a way to compare the performance of these clusters. [This website](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-tips-for-choosing-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-277e93d72d92) suggests ten ways to "tentatively" guess the optimal number of clusters, but they don't work for a rather large data set and return the memory error message.

My Question: Is there any method(package) which can do the same task but is not this memory greedy so that I can run the test?

My machine has 64 GB of RAM, and its virtual memory is 171 GB.
Thank you!

Comment: The website that you refer to lists the elbow method as a way of choosing the number of clusters. Since you succeeded in clustering the data for k=2 through 10,  just compute the within-cluster sum of the squares.

Comment: @G5W I tried to use the code they provided for the elbow method, but it returns the error message. Is there any "tweak" you can think of that solves the problem?

Comment: Yes,  Instead of using `fviz_nbclust`   just compute the within-cluster sum of the squares yourself (and then plot them.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering))

Comment: you might look at the High-performance task view (google it) to see if there's a package out there that's targeted at large-scale clustering ...

Answer (score 1):

The Elbow method uses only a statistic already computed by k-means, so it does not even access the data. However, it is not even well defined and works exceptionally poor except on 2d toy data as used in class. So I would not recommend it. At least use WSS/(k+1) instead or better the VRC.

Most likely k-means does not work on your data. Be prepared to accept that maybe none of the results is good, because your data does not satisfy the requirements of k-means (e.g., all attributes have the same importance and scale, are linear and not heavily skewed, and all clusters have similar extend). In particular that last one - similar extend of clusters - only hold when your data is actually generated by k pure signals and i.i.d. noise. If your data is rather coming from users it will likely not work. In such cases, above heuristics also will not help much in choosing k...

Now for your scalability problem: just use a **subsample**.

K-means is averaging, and so are most of the quality measures. For averages subsampling will give you very similar results to the entire data set. So just subsample 10k or even just 1k of your points and use only that set for evaluation (or even for clustering). If in doubt, evaluate several times with different subsamples.

Comment: As for the data, the variables are the number of friends, followers, and statuses of 1,100,000 twitter accounts. I think the variables are somewhat equally important, but as you mentioned the data is very heavily skewed to the right. Of course, I log-transformed and then normalized my data before using k-means. In light of my new explanations, do you still think K-means is not appropriate? If not, what method would you recommend? I also appreciate it if you explain a little bit more (or recommend source) about how to subsample and how to extend the results to the whole sample.

Comment: Actually I doubt there will be clusters in this data. Log is problematic because log(0)=-infinity. Have you done a PCA to visualize the data? If you can't see clusters in the PCA, KMeans won't find good clusters either.

Comment: I added 1 to the values to evade the log(0) problem. as for PCA, here's the results of the variance explained by each of the three principal components: ```0.79423096, 0.14889490, 0.05687413``` . Do you still think Kmeans is not useful here? if so, could you think of a more appropriate technique? Again, I am trying to cluster twitter users based on the number of their friends, followers, and statuses.

Comment: Well, I don't know what the plot looks like. But 85% of variance in the first two components means that the 2d plot will give you a good idea of what k-means works on. If there is only one big blob there, any k-means split will be as good as random.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I have found and modified to "tentatively" suggest likely optimal clusters based om @G5W comment on using `elbow method` and `within-cluster sum of the squares`

```
# Determine number of clusters
wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var)) 
for (i in 2:9) { 
   wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers = i)$withinss) 
}  

# Plot the clusters 
plot(1:9, wss, type = "b", xlab = "Number of Clusters", 
   ylab = "Within groups sum of squares")
```